# Prevent backspace from navigating back in AngularJS Model Window

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-model

I am using angular model service ($modal) display pop-up. I am facing a problem like when user click backspace on the model window, parent window gets navigating to previous page. How do i resolve this?

Comment: asking your users to stop pressing the backspace key? This is a navigation shortcut that exists on every browser if the focus is not in an input.

Answer (score 0):

In your $modal.open() set the following:

```
backdrop: 'static'
keyboard: false
```

Comment: Hi, 
This seems doesn't work., Because keyboard: false will disable browser close on ESC key event not works with backspace on model window

Comment: Yes, this also overrides the esc key behavior.  You can give the user a button to cancel out of the modal in lieu of the esc key.  I think that's a little cleaner anyhow.